# Find which process receives a given keyboard command

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut

I'm trying to figure out why a certain keyboard combination is no longer working.

As an example, Sublime Text 2 ships with a keyboard shortcut for opening the Find/Replace panel:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

This combo worked fine until I did a clean install of OSX 10.8.5, after which it mysteriously stopped working in Sublime Text.

I know keyboard sequences can be captured by processes other than the frontmost (like by the OS) so I was wondering if there is a way of checking by which process a particular keyboard command was "consumed"?

Comment: For VSCode CMD+SHIFT+P, see https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/250

Answer (score 64):

[ShortcutDetective](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/) solves your problem. It's free, simple, and to the point.

Comment: Fantastic recommendation! This did the trick for me.

Comment: Thank you!!! This saved me from losing my sanity!

Comment: Awesome software, but doesn't seem to work for media keys/shortcuts : [

Comment: Great, this app really helps.

Comment: After migrating my Intel MacBook Pro to a new Apple Silicon (M1 Max) Macbook Pro, ShortcutDetective sometimes crashes for me. Is anyone else experiencing this problem? (I used it so often that I would keep it running on my side monitor, but because of this, not anymore. It's still useful for one-off problems, like the OP's question.)

Comment: Yep, I also got a crash on my M1 MacBook Air, but it worked long enough to tell me which app was stealing the keyboard shortcut I was trying to use (it was Logitech Options, and updating it fixed the problem).

Comment: It hasn't been updated in years.  It crashes every time a shortcut is trigger that's handled by the system (e.g. Shortcuts defined in System Preferences)

Comment: This doesn't crash for me but it doesn't work at all in Sonoma. Doesn't detect any keypresses at all. Just spins.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know any fast and efficient method to find the recipient of a shortcut. But here is a *receipe* to initiate the hunt:

1. Close most of your running applications so as to improve the efficiency of the hunt.
2. Open a `Terminal` window, and run the following command:

   ```
   /usr/bin/sudo opensnoop | more
   ```

This command will track down every `open` system call.

3. Switch to the context where your shortcut is intercepted by an unknown application and type <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd>+<kbd>⌥ option</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>.

Look for a culprit hint from the file names opened.

4. `while` unsuccessfull, add one application, and
   `GOTO 3`.

Comment: Nice! If you do this fast enough, you should have a pretty succinct list of processes. I had about 50 lines, half of which were a background process I knew wasn't listening to keyboard presses so I was easily able to filter those out in a text editor. The remaining 20 or so lines recorded 3 other processes, and 75% of them contained my culprit. Thanks so much for sharing, @daniel

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'd been frustrated for ages that something else was capturing a shortcut meant for one of my applications (and even worse, playing a little ping sound!). ran this, saw maybe 4 apps making calls, one of them was opening "ping.aiff", led me straight to the culprit!

Comment: I used this method to find that, frustratingly, Logi Tune is capturing CMD+N. Worked perfectly.

Comment: This worked great, but in macOS 12 it seems that `opensnoop` isn't working because of System Integrity Protection.

Comment: Do you get an error message or did you read this limitation within `man opensnoop`?

Comment: @dan the message is : probe description syscall::open:entry does not match any probes. System Integrity Protection is on

Comment: @AndreyMishchenko: then I suggest you to **temporarily** turn off System Integrity Protection. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208478/how-do-i-disable-system-integrity-protection-sip-aka-rootless-on-macos

Comment: `sudo fs_usage -f filesys` can get you there without having to mess with the System Integrity Protection

Comment: @jgreen You should create an answer for this solution. It's infinitely simpler on newer MacOS's.

Comment: Both `sudo opensnoop` and `sudo fs_usage -f filesys` give me a constant stream of output. How can I narrow this down to finding the app that is intercepting a keyboard shortcut? I'm saavy with the command line, so `grep` or `awk` or something would be fine.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : Since the name you are looking for is the enigma, `grep` like tools won't be of any use. My method is hit [ctl]+[C] in the shell where `opensnoop` or `fs_usage` is running, and scroll back a few lines.

Comment: @dan Thanks for your reply. On the system where I was trying to use opensnoop/fs_usage, the output was so fast that in the time it takes to hit [Ctrl]+[C], there are probably at least a hundred of lines to scroll through and no way for me to know how far back I need to scroll. Which is why I was asking about how to automate this more.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice : just use `| more` to slow them down.

Comment: @dan I think that just moves the problem to the other end. Now I have to figure out how far to scroll down from the top instead of up from the bottom.

Comment: This looks cool but I have no idea what this is supposed to be doing or how this is going to help me. It also says: "dtrace: invalid probe specifier"

Answer (score 3):

`sudo fs_usage -f filesys` can get you there without having to mess with the System Integrity Protection.

---

This was initially a comment on [Find which process receives a given keyboard command](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/177058/291138) and was suggested to be added as an answer. Unfortunately, it was a while ago so I don't remember how exactly this was helpful but at least some people found it useful.

Comment: This moves too fast to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

KeyCue provides visual feedback on the keyboard shortcuts.  It can be downloaded as a trial version.

[KeyCue from Ergonis](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/)

I have it configured so that a double tap and hold on the Command key displays all the currently active shortcuts.

Comment: After trying KeyCue, it looks to me like it only shows the keyboard shortcuts associated with menu commands for the current active application.  Additionally, it seems to show global hotkeys from Keybaord Maestro and maybe one or two other specific supported applications.  Does it show global hotkeys for _all_ applications for you?

Comment: I find it somewhat mysterious as to what hotkeys are shown for 'other' apps.  I think it attempts (but doesn't fully succeed) to show global hotkeys that are relevant to where you are. The User Guide specifically refers to Keyboard Maestro.