# Tool to find use of keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut

Is there a way to figure out who (if anyone) is intercepting a given keystroke sequence? I'd like an answer in general (e.g. is there a tool that will do this?). In my particular case, though, I'm pretty sure that someone is intercepting Ctrl-F1, and I'd like to know who.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/104074/find-which-process-receives-a-given-keyboard-command?rq=1 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/145582/how-to-display-the-current-mapping-for-keyboard-shortcuts-in-realtime

Answer (score -1):

I use http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/labs/ for this problem. https://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/ is usefull as well